# Get the index of a pattern in a string using regex with Kotlin

Tags: android, regex, kotlin

I want to search a string for a specific pattern with kotlin.

Do the regular expression classes provide the positions (indexes within the string) of the pattern within the string?

Comment: The `MatchResult` object has the [`range` property](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-match-result/range.html): "*The range of indices in the original string where match was captured.*". Also, [`MatchGroup`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-match-group/index.html) has a `range` property, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [MatchResult](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-match-result/index.html) object has the [range](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-match-result/range.html) property:

> The range of indices in the original string where match was captured.

Also, [MatchGroup](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-match-group/index.html) has a `range` property, too.

A [short demo](https://rextester.com/ZBBEJ55581) showing the range of the first match of a whole word `long`:

```
val strs = listOf("Long days become shorter","winter lasts longer")
val pattern = """(?i)\blong\b""".toRegex()
strs.forEach { str ->
    val found = pattern.find(str)
    if (found != null) {
      val m = found?.value
      val idx = found?.range
      println("'$m' found at indexes $idx in '$str'")
    }
}
// => 'Long' found at indexes 0..3 in 'long days become shorter'
```